# How to properly add new child with children in xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml, api

An API returns the following, and I want to add another data record for testing purposes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<API>
    <code>0000</code>
    <time>1549959757</time>
    <data cnt="1">
        <record>
        <record>
            <approval_idx>224833</approval_idx>
            <reg_date>2019-02-12</reg_date>
            <user_id>test</user_id>
            <state1>10</state1>
            <state2>03</state2>
            <name>tester</name>
            <e_id>3743</e_id>
            <cname>test cname</cname>
            <cId>3089</cId>
            <loc>oh</loc>
        </record>
        </record>
    </data>
</API>
```

I tried doing this

```
$utilApi = new libUtilApi($apiRequest);
$utilApi->request();
$resultAPI = $utilApi->response;
$resultAPI = simplexml_load_string($resultAPI);
$record = $resultAPI->addChild("record");
$record->addChild("approval_idx", "7546");
```

but the output look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<API>
    <code>0000</code>
    <time>1549959757</time>
    <data cnt="1">
        <record>
        <record>
            <approval_idx>224833</approval_idx>
            <reg_date>2019-02-12</reg_date>
            <user_id>test</user_id>
            <state1>10</state1>
            <state2>03</state2>
            <name>tester</name>
            <e_id>3743</e_id>
            <cname>test cname</cname>
            <cId>3089</cId>
            <branch>oh</branch>
        </record>
        </record>
        <record>
            <approval_idx>7546</approval_idx>
            <reg_date>2019-02-13</reg_date>
            <user_id>test3</user_id>
            <state1>75</state1>
            <state2>09</state2>
            <name>new test</name>
            <e_id>7546</e_id>
            <cname>Q1</cname>
            <cId>325</cId>
            <branch>oh</branch>
        </record>
    </data>
</API>
```

The added child is not going in right position, I tried

```
$record = $resultAPI->record[0]->addChild("record");
```

but it falls to an error like:

> Call to a member function `addChild()` on `null`

-I just updated the code, yes the api is returning the proper format and data, its just that I can't make the addition of children on the right place

Comment: Your original XML is invalid: it has three opening `<record>` tags, but only one closing `</record>` tag. Note I fixed the indentation; please make sure to use proper indentation when you correct this.

Comment: oh sorry for that. 

it was my mistake, it  has a closing tag. Thank you!

Comment: o nvm. fixed it by cloning. Thank You!~